# permanently removing read only option

Tags: 13.04, boot, grub2, kernel, read-only

I have ubuntu 13.04 and kernel 3.11.

When I press `e` key at grub bootmenu I see the read only `ro` option at root partition and when I start system with that option I have low resolution and other problems.
Otherwise removing `ro` option before starting the system makes everything work fine.

I would like to know how to permanently remove `ro` option.
I have already checked `/etc/default/grub` but there is no `ro`, here is my grub:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=false
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

How can I do that? What file do we see when using `e` key at grub bootmenu? If I know that maybe I'll be able to edit it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you're looking for is `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`. Look for the line

```
linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${linux_root_device_thisversion} ro ${args}
```

and remove `ro` from it. You should then let `grub` update its `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` by running

```
sudo update-grub
```

You shouldn't edit the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` manually as it will be restored to default each time you upgrade the `grub` package.

**Edit**

That said, it's probably not a good idea to remove the `ro` parameter. This parameter is there for a reason: it's so that filesystem consistency check (`fsck`) utilities can work safely on the root device at boot time. Your `/etc/fstab` then ensures that it will get remounted `rw`. See `man bootparam`

Comment: ok great thanks I'll try it, do you it's safe to remove ro from root partition?

Comment: @Frank It's probably not a good idea. This parameter is there for a reason: it's so that filesystem consistency check (`fsck`) utilities can work safely on the root device at boot time. Your `/etc/fstab` then ensures that it will get remounted `rw`. See `man bootparam`.

Answer (score 0):

The file which your are looking for is in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but don't ask me further how to configure it.. ;) I really don't know.

At least I can suggest you these links:

- [Grub2/Setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup)
- [Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)
- [Grub2 Basics](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275)

I would like you to edit my post and give possible solution once you overcome from your issues. I hope it helps you somewhat to get your solution.